# Reading a file into class variables and an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

The contents of the files are:

[Contents of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVrKi.png)

The first three lines of the file contain the teacher's name, the subject, and class period which each go into separate class variables:
String teacherName, String subject, String period.

The rest of the file contain all the arguments for a Student object which has the signature of:

Student(String name, int studentID, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3, int grade4, int grade5, int grade6, int grade7, int grade8, int grade9, int grade10)

I am confused on how to input the student's name into the array because it contains a space between it so when I try to use .next() it only get the last name of the student and not their full name, any idea on how to input it?

Comment: will student name always appears first in every line after 4th line ?

Comment: yes it will since the first three always contain the teacher, subject and period

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use the file that way, and you are sure, that the studentId always starts with a number, you could just split your line first by checking for the first appearance of a number.

However if you can change the delimiter, I would highly recommend to use something like a semicolon.

Comment: how would you recommend changing the file?

Comment: I would use a different kind of separator between your entries. For example:
Name;Id;grad1 and so on

Comment: Line by line by using a FileReader. There are many examples how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Smth. like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Data data = new Data();

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("data.txt")))) {
            data.setTeacherName(in.readLine());
            data.setSubject(in.readLine());
            data.setPeriod(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));

            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] studentData = str.split(";");
                Data.Student student = new Data.Student();
                student.setName(studentData[0]);
                student.setId(Integer.parseInt(studentData[1]));

                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    student.addGrade(j, Integer.parseInt(studentData[j + 2]));

                data.addStudent(student);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data.class**

```
public class Data {
    private String teacherName;
    private String subject;
    private int period;
    private Map<Integer, Student> students = new HashMap<>();

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.put(student.getId(), student);
    }

    public static final class Student {
        private String name;
        private int id;
        private int[] grades = new int[10];

        public void addGrade(int pos, int value) {
            if (pos < grades.length)
                grades[pos] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, if you know that student's name could have `space`, thhen you are able to use **any delimeter** except `space`.

In general usage, `csv` is simple to create and to ready. But if your data structure is more complicated and has hierarcy, e.g. like in your example, but with multiple teachers in one file, then I recommend you to look at another format: **YAML**.

Answer (score 0):

First create a simple model for storing student marks. I name this model as Student. Below is the code for student model.

```
    public class Student {
         int[] marks;
         public Student(){
             this.marks = new int[10];
         }


        public void setMark(int i, int score){
            marks[i] = score;
        }
    }
```

Then read the first three lines as usual. Then loop through all lines while creating and storing student object in an array list as below.

`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileConnector {
    public void readFile(String fileName){
        String line =null;
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String teachersName = line;
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String subject =line;
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            int period =  Integer.valueOf(line);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Student student = new Student();
                String[] marks =line.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
                    student.setMark(i,Integer.parseInt(marks[i]));
                }
                students.add(student);
            }


            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Unable to open file '" +
                            fileName + "'");
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error reading file '"
                            + fileName + "'");
            // Or we could just do this:
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`
Now you can call this from main method as

```
    FileConnector fileConnector = new FileConnector();
    fileConnector.readFile();
```